# AH00046: child process {pid} still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL

Tags: linux, apache

We hosted our wordpress site in linux apache. We are using apache version 2.4

Our site getting timeout issue and getting downtime frequently or we will face delayed response from site.

While validating apache error logs we are seeing this below

> AH00046: child process {pid} still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL

1. We priorly used event MPM then we changes to perfork. But still issue occurs. Do we need to change to worker MPM to resolve this?
2. We tried to increase maxrequestworker limit also. But that too not resolving issue.

Any wordpress plugin level problem also will cause this error? Other than MPM and maxrequestworker, do we need to check any other scenarios?

Thanks in advance.